# Is it possible to utilize the convergence of the sequence $z_{n+1}=a/(1+z_n)$ to prove that the sequence $x_{n+2} = \sqrt{x_{n+1} x_n}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

I'm doing *Problem II.4.6* in textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher.

> For $x_0,x_1 \in \mathbb R^+$, the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ defined recursively by $x_{n+2} = \sqrt{x_{n+1} x_n}$ is convergent.

**My questions:**

1. I'm not sure if my attempt (the parts from **Lemma 4** to the end) is fine or contains logical gaps/errors. Could you please verify these parts? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Particularly, I'm not sure if my induction in case $m > n$ in the part "...$\color{blue}{\text{vacuously true}}$ ..."  and the proof that *there exists $0 < \beta < 1$ such that $y_{n+1} \le \beta y_n$* are correct or not.

2. There is *Problem II.4.5* as follows:

> For $z_0,a \in \mathbb R^+$ , the sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$  defined recursively by $z_{n+1}=a/(1+z_n)$  is convergent.

Using Mathematica, I found that both of the sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ share the same plot as follows.

[image]

I would like to ask whether it is possible to utilize the convergence of $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ to prove the convergence of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

First we consider the case $x_0 < x_1$.

> **Lemma 1:** $x_{2n} < x_{2n+1}$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** The statement trivially holds for $n=0$. Let it hold for some $n$. We have $$\begin{aligned} x_{2(n+1)} < x_{2(n+1)+1} & \iff x_{2n+2} < x_{2n+3} \\ &\iff \sqrt{x_{2n+1} x_{2n}} < \sqrt{x_{2n+2} x_{2n+1}} \\ &\iff  x_{2n} < x_{2n+2}  \\ &\iff x_{2n} < \sqrt{x_{2n+1} x_{2n}} \\&\iff x_{2n} < x_{2n+1}\quad (\star) \end{aligned}$$ in which $(\star)$ follows from inductive hypothesis. As such, the statement holds for $n+1$.

> **Lemma 2:** $x_{2n} < x_{2n+2}$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** We have $x_{2n} < x_{2n+2} \iff x_{2n} < \sqrt{x_{2n+1} x_{2n}} \iff x_{2n} < x_{2n+1}$, which is true by **Lemma 1**. As a consequence, $(x_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is increasing.

> **Lemma 3:** $x_{2n+3} < x_{2n+1}$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** We have $x_{2n+3} < x_{2n+1} \iff \sqrt{x_{2n+2} x_{2n+1}} < x_{2n+1} \iff x_{2n+2} < x_{2n+1} \iff$ $\sqrt{x_{2n+1} x_{2n}} < x_{2n+1} \iff x_{2n} < x_{2n+1}$, which is true by **Lemma 1**. As a consequence, $(x_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is decreasing.

> **Lemma 4:** $x_{2m} < x_{2n+1}$ for all $m,n$.

**Proof:** In case $m \le n$, we have $x_{2m} \overset{(\star)}{\le} x_{2n} \overset{(\star\star)}{<} x_{2n+1}$ in which $(\star)$ follows from the fact that $(x_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is increasing, and $(\star\star)$ follows from **Lemma 1**.

We prove the statement in case $m > n$ by induction on $m$. It's $\color{blue}{\text{vacuously true}}$ for $m=0$. Let it hold for some $m$. We have $$\begin{aligned} x_{2(m+1)} < x_{2n+1} & \iff x_{2m+2} < x_{2n+1} \\ &\iff \sqrt{x_{2m+1} x_{2m}} < x_{2n+1} \\ &\iff  x_{2m+1} x_{2m} < x^2_{2n+1} \quad (\star) \end{aligned}$$ in which $(\star)$ follows from $x_{2m} < x_{2n+1}$ (by inductive hypothesis) and from $x_{2m+1} < x_{2n+1}$ (by $m > n$ and $(x_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is decreasing). As such, the statement holds for $n+1$.

We define the sequence $(y_n)$ by $y_n := x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}$. We next prove that there exists $0 < \beta < 1$ such that $y_{n+1} \le \beta y_n$ for all $n$.

$$\begin{aligned} y_{n+1} < \beta y_n &\iff x_{2(n+1)+1} - x_{2(n+1)} < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}) \\ &\iff x_{2n+3} - x_{2n+2} < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}) \\&\iff \sqrt{x_{2n+2} x_{2n+1}} - x_{2n+2} < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}) \\ &\iff \sqrt{x_{2n+2}} (\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} - \sqrt{x_{2n+2}}) < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n})\end{aligned}$$

Since $x_{2n+2} > x_{2n}$, $\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} - \sqrt{x_{2n+2}} < \sqrt{x_{2n+1}} - \sqrt{x_{2n}}$. As such, it suffices to prove that there exists $0 < \beta < 1$ such that $\sqrt{x_{2n+2}} (\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} - \sqrt{x_{2n}}) < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n})$. We have

$$\begin{aligned} &\sqrt{x_{2n+2}} (\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} - \sqrt{x_{2n}}) < \beta (x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}) \\ &\iff \sqrt{x_{2n+2}} < \beta (\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} + \sqrt{x_{2n}}) \\ &\iff \dfrac{\sqrt{x_{2n+2}}}{\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} + \sqrt{x_{2n}}} < \beta \\&\iff \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{x_{2n+2}}}{\sqrt{x_{2n+1}} + \sqrt{x_{2n}}}\right)^2 < \beta^2  \\ &\iff \dfrac{x_{2n+2}}{x_{2n+1} + 2\sqrt{x_{2n+1} x_{2n}} + x_{2n}} < \beta^2 \\ &\iff \dfrac{x_{2n+2}}{x_{2n+1} + 2x_{2n+2} + x_{2n}} < \beta^2\\ &\iff \dfrac{1}{2+ x_{2n+1}/x_{2n+2} + x_{2n}/x_{2n+2}} < \beta^2  \end{aligned}$$

As a result, we are done if we choose $1/\sqrt{2} <\beta < 1$. Then $y_{n+1} \le \beta y_n$ and thus $y_{n} \le \beta^n y_0$ for all $n$. We have $0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta^n y_0 = 0$. As such, $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = 0$ and so $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n+1} = \alpha$.

From **Lemmas 2**,**3**, and **4**, our sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ looks like $$x_0 < x_2 < x_4 < \cdots < x_{2n}< \cdots <x_{2n+1} < \cdots <x_5<x_3<x_1$$

By Nested Intervals Theorem, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n+1}$$

Next we prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \alpha$$

**Approach 1:** For $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_{2n} - \alpha| < \varepsilon$ and $|x_{2n+1} - \alpha| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$. Thus $|x_{n} - \alpha| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > 2N$. As a result, $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \alpha$.

**Approach 2:**

Given $n \in \mathbb N$, we have $A := \{2k+1 \in \mathbb N \mid k \ge n\} \subseteq B := \{k \in \mathbb N \mid k \ge n\}$ and, for each $k \in B$, there exists $k' \in A$ such that $x_k \le x_{k'}$. As such, $\sup_{k \ge n} x_{k} = \sup_{k \ge n} x_{2k+1}$ and thus $\inf_{n \ge 0} \sup_{k \ge n} x_{k} = \inf_{n \ge 0} \sup_{k \ge n} x_{2k+1}$. Similarly, we have $\sup_{n \ge 0} \inf_{k \ge n} x_{2k} =$ $\sup_{n \ge 0} \inf_{k \ge n} x_{k}$. It follows that $$\alpha = \sup_{n \ge 0} \inf_{k \ge n} x_{2k} = \sup_{n \ge 0} \inf_{k \ge n} x_{k} \le \inf_{n \ge 0} \sup_{k \ge n} x_{k} = \inf_{n \ge 0} \sup_{k \ge n} x_{2k+1} = \alpha$$ and thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = \alpha$.

The case $x_0 > x_1$ is similar, while the case $x_0 = x_1$ is trivial.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651794/prove-that-sequence-x-n1-frac-a1x-n-is-convergent-to-positive-roo/3656653#3656653) is a solution for the *Problem II*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is quite long. Here is a **hint** for a shorter one. What about $y_n=\log{x_n}$ then
$$x_{n+2}=\sqrt{x_{n+1}x_n} \Rightarrow \\
\log{x_{n+2}}=\frac{\log{x_{n+1}}+\log{x_n}}{2} \Rightarrow \\
2y_{n+2}=y_{n+1}+y_{n}$$
which is a linear homegenious recurrence which can be solved using [characteristic polynomials](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial). I.e. characteristic polynomial is
$$2x^2-x-1=0$$
with $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ as the roots. Thus the general term of the sequence is
$$y_n=A\cdot 1^n+B\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=
A+B\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
or
$$x_n=e^{A}\cdot e^{B\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}\to e^A, n\to\infty$$
$A$ can be found from the initial $x_0,x_1$. A few examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922952/finding-a-closed-form-x-n-for-the-recurrence-relation-x-n2-px-n1-qx/), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559687/show-that-the-sequence-a-1-1-a-2-2-a-n2-a-n1a-n-2-converges-b/2559826#2559826) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547762/recursion-y-n-ky-n-1ry-n-2-y-0-2-y-1-k-and-fermat-theorem/2548686#2548686).

Comment: Honestly, I'm only at the point about convergence of monotone sequence in my textbook. Your solution is simple (and thus elegant), but I could not understand it at this time. Could you please have a check on my suspected parts?

Comment: @LeAnhDung my goal was to show you a different technique, with examples and a link to a very detailed material.

Answer (score 2):

Here is as
elementary a proof
as I can come up with
that
the limit exists
and
the limit is
$\sqrt[3]{x_1^2 x_0}
$.

$x_{n+2} = \sqrt{x_{n+1} x_n}
$,
so, taking logs,

$\begin{array}\\
\log x_{n+2} 
&= \log\sqrt{x_{n+1} x_n}\\
&= \frac12 \log(x_{n+1} x_n)\\
&= \frac12 (\log x_{n+1} +\log x_n)\\
&= \frac12 \log x_{n+1} +\frac12 \log x_n\\
\end{array}
$

Letting
$y_n = \log x_n$,
this becomes
$y_{n+2}
=\frac12 (y_{n+1}+y_n)
$.

$y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}
=\frac12 (y_{n+1}+y_n)-y_{n+1}
=-\frac12(y_{n+1}-y_n)
$.

By induction,
for $k > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}
&=-\frac12(y_{n+1}-y_n)\\
&=\frac14(y_{n}-y_{n-1})\\
&=-\frac18(y_{n-1}-y_{n-2})\\
&...\\
&=(-1)^k\dfrac1{2^k}(y_{n+2-k}-y_{n+1-k})\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac1{2^{n+1}}(y_{1}-y_{0})
\qquad\text{by setting }k = n+1\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

This shows that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$
exists.

(Actually,
a bit more is needed,
but the following
gives an explicit value
so you don't need
to worry about it.)

To get the value,
sum the expression for
$y_{n+1}-y_n$;
all the intermediate terms
will cancel out.

Write it in the form
$y_{n}-y_{n-1}
=(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac1{2^{n-1}}(y_{1}-y_{0})
=(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{d}{2^{n-1}}
$
where
$d 
= y_{1}-y_{0}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
y_m-y_1
&=\sum_{n=2}^m (y_n-y_{n-1})\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^m (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{d}{2^{n-1}}\\
&=d\sum_{n=2}^m (-\frac12)^{n-1}\\
&=d\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (-\frac12)^{n}\\
&=d\dfrac{-\frac12-(-\frac12)^m}{1-(-\frac12)}\\
&=d\dfrac{-\frac12-(-\frac12)^m}{\frac32}\\
&=d\dfrac{-1-2(-\frac12)^m}{3}\\
&=d(-\dfrac13-\dfrac23(-\frac12)^m)\\
&=-\dfrac{y_1-y_0}{3}-\dfrac{2(y_1-y_0)}{3}(-\frac12)^m\\
\end{array}
$

so
$y_m
=\dfrac{2y_1+y_0}{3}-\dfrac{2(y_1-y_0)}{3}(-\frac12)^m
\to\dfrac{2y_1+y_0}{3}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\log x_m
&\to \dfrac{2y_1+y_0}{3}\\
&= \dfrac{2\log(x_1)+\log(x_0)}{3}\\
&= \dfrac{\log(x_1^2 x_0)}{3}\\
&= \log(\sqrt[3]{x_1^2 x_0})\\
\end{array}
$

so
$x_m
\to \sqrt[3]{x_1^2 x_0}
$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_{n+2} 
= \sqrt{x_{n+1} x_n}
$.

Suppose
$x_n
=x_0^{a(n)}x_1^{b(n)}
$
with
$a(0) = 1, b(0) = 0,
a(1) = 0, b(1) = 1
$.
Then
$x_0^{a(n+2)}x_1^{b(n+2)}
=\sqrt{x_0^{a(n+1)}x_1^{b(n+1)}x_0^{a(n)}x_1^{b(n)}}
=x_0^{(a(n+1)+a(n))/2}x_1^{(b(n+1)+b(n))/2}
$
so that
$a(n+2)
=(a(n+1)+a(n))/2,
b(n+2)
=(b(n+1)+b(n))/2
$.

Both
$a(n)$ and $b(n)$
are of the form
$ru^n+sv^n$
where
$u$ and $v$ are the roots of
$x^2=(x+1)/2
$
or
$2x^2-x-1=0
$,
These are
$x_{\pm}
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8}}{4}
=\dfrac{1\pm 3}{4}
=1, -\dfrac12
$.
We will use
$u = 1, v = -\frac12$.

If
$a(n)
=r_au^n+s_av^n
=r_a+s_a(-1/2)^n
$
and
$b(n)
=r_bu^n+s_bv^n
=r_b+s_b(-1/2)^n
$
then,
setting $n=0, 1$,

$1 = r_a+s_a,\\
0 = r_a-s_a/2,\\
0 = r_b+s_b,\\
1 = r_b-s_b/2,\\
$

so
$r_a = \frac13,
s_a = \frac23,
r_b = \frac23,
s_b = -\frac23
$.

$\begin{array}\\
x_n
&=x_0^{a(n)}x_1^{b(n)}\\
&=x_0^{r_a+s_a(-1/2)^n}x_1^{r_b+s_b(-1/2)^n}\\
&=x_0^{\frac13+\frac23(-1/2)^n}x_1^{\frac23-\frac23(-1/2)^n}\\
&\to x_0^{\frac13}x_1^{\frac23}
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Honestly, I'm only at the point about convergence of monotone sequence in my textbook. Your solution is simple (and thus elegant), but I could not understand it at this time. Could you please have a check on my suspected parts?

Answer (score -2):

you dont need Lemma 4 to show the convergence. Lemma I-III show, that the even and uneven subsequence are bounded and monoton. Thus convergent. Now show that those limits are equal and you are done.(use the computational rules of limes) BTW: Im working on the same book at the moment, but I'm a chapter ahead of you :D

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "computational rules of limes"?

Comment: Let $a=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n}$ and $b=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n+1}$. $b=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{2n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{x_{2n}}*\sqrt{x_{2n-1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{x_{2n}}*\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{x_{2n-1}}=\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b}$

Comment: I got it @Josep. Many thanks for you!

Comment: I would like to ask if you can apply the same technique to solve this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323028/a-shorter-proof-for-the-theorem-for-x-0-a-in-mathbb-r-the-sequence-x-n.

Comment: Yes; it makes your proof a lot shorter. You can make it even shorter if you can verify this fact: $a>0$. Now the function $f(x)=a/({1+x})$ has exactly one positive fixpoint. Let b be that Fixpoint. Now you can show, that for $x_0>b\:: x_{2n}$ is increasing and  $x_{2n+1}$ is decreasing. Both are bounded.($0$ and a)  In the case $x_0<b\::  x_{2n}$ is decreasing  and  $x_{2n+1}$ is increasing. $x_0=b$ and the sequence is constant. All cases result in monoton bounded subsequences. Now use the technique I just showed you and you are done.

Comment: Let $\alpha := \lim x_{2n+1}, \beta:= \lim x_{2n}$. We have $\alpha = a/(1 +\beta)$. Then I'm stuck :(

Comment: use the same argument again.. but for $\beta=\dots$

Comment: You mean $x_{2n}=a/(1+x_{2n-1})$ and thus $\beta = a/(1+\alpha)$?

Comment: Yes. As a result $a=\alpha+\alpha\cdot\beta=\beta+\beta\cdot\alpha$

Comment: Thank you so much :)